# how to validate my users login information

Tags: php, html

I have an html form where the user is requested to Enter his name and password

```
<html>
<body>

<formaction="welcome.php"method="post">
Name: <inputtype="text"name="name"><br>
Password: <inputtype="text"name="pass.   word"><br>
<input type="create">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and from the code above you will see I see a php page where the informations are sent to (form handler /form processor)

now I created another page for login in to the account created

```
<html>
<body>

<form>
Name: <inputtype="text"name="name"><br>
    Password: <inputtype="text"name="password"><br>
<input type="Login">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

what I want is for the login page to go and check the welcome page (form handler /form processor) where the registered informations were sent to, to know if the account/user exists if yes open to the homepage.html but if no reset the page

but I don't know where to go from here someone please help me

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Note `<inputtype="text"name="name">` WRONG `<input type="text" name="name">` much better

Answer (score -1):

Using PHP, you need to implement sessions.

Try this at the top of both php files:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Then, once you've verified that the user has authority to login you can do something like.

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
```

Then you can access that session variable from any file that you enabled sessions on.

Comment: where I am having problems is trying check if the information provided in the "login in" form by the user is valid / if the information provided is correct information of any account created earlier

Comment: There are two ways to check it. You can use javascript on the front end or PHP on the back end after the form is submitted.

You're going to have to clarify what you've done and tested and what errors you've gotten before anyone can help you more.